# mod_rewrite - HTTP to HTTPS redirection rule only works after accessing it through HTTP first

Tags: mod-rewrite, https, elastic-beanstalk, tomcat8

I have a Tomcat 8 app deployed on Elastic Beanstalk which uses a sub-domain of my main app. Both are separate applications and do not interact. I have a `mod_rewrite` rule to redirect all `http` requests to `https` in a configuration file in the `.ebextensions` folder -

```
files:
  "/etc/httpd/conf.d/httpd_redirect.conf" :
    mode: "000644"
    owner: root
    group: root
    content: |
      LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
      RewriteEngine On
      RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
      RewriteRule (.*) https://sub.domain.com%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R]
```

So ideally, someone accessing the app at `sub.domain.com` or `http://sub.domain.com` will be redirected to `https://sub.domain.com`.

The problem is that this works only after I request the app with `https` first. So, I have to request `https://sub.domain.com` first, and from then onwards, `non-https` requests will be redirected to `https`.

Also, this only works until I clear my browser cache. Once the cache is cleared, `non-https` requests are no longer redirected to `https`. I have make an `https` request first again for the redirection to start working.

What could be causing this? The main domain uses a separate certificate from that of the sub-domain if it matters.

How can I force the application to always use `https`?

I have a secure listener enabled on the load balancer with this configuration file in `.ebextensions` -

```
option_settings:
  aws:elb:listener:443:
    SSLCertificateId: arn:aws:acm:us-east-2:1234567890123:certificate/####################################
    ListenerProtocol: HTTPS
    InstancePort: 80
```

Comment: See the answer to this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26679186/force-user-to-access-the-site-using-https-only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was not with the rewrite rule. The file had to be placed in a specific path within `.ebextensions` for it to work in Tomcat 8. The configuration files had to be setup differently too. Most examples provided were not for Tomcat so I ended up putting them in the wrong location.

**What worked** -

In `/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/myconf.conf`, place -

```
LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so
```

and in `/.ebextensions/httpd/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/00_application.conf`, place -

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  <Proxy *:80>
    Order Allow,Deny
    Allow from all
  </Proxy>
  ProxyPass / http://localhost:8080/ retry=0
  ProxyPassReverse / http://localhost:8080/
  ProxyPreserveHost on

  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteCond %{HTTP:X-Forwarded-Proto} =http
  RewriteRule . https://%{HTTP:Host}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=permanent]

  ErrorLog /var/log/httpd/elasticbeanstalk-error_log
</VirtualHost>
```

*Take note of the use of `.conf` files instead of `.config`. This is important!*

Also, the false sense of redirection that I was getting was due to the browser cache serving me the `https` site. This is why it would not work when I cleared my cache.

Comment: I don't get it. You are forcing all traffic through 443 -> 80 -> 8080, but there is no added value of 80 (like serving static html files). Maybe go 443 -> 8080 and use 80 only for redirect. This problem has nothing to do with Apache Tomcat, and all to do with **Apache httpd**.

Comment: @kubanczyk As implied by my answer, neither of them were the problem. The problem was with the location of the rewrite rule config file in `.ebextensions` which Elastic Beanstalk uses for container configuration during deployment. They had a different implementation for Tomcat which I wasn't aware of and the problem was solved once I placed it in the right location.